# enemy.rect does not update

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I've been working on my project about tanks (similar to tank trouble) and I have a bug. Let me explain.

When an enemy spawns and I shoot at it, the collision counts. But as soon as I move the enemy and shoot at it again, the collision doesn't count. I think that there is a problem with `self.rect` in `Enemy()` class.

Also, `if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):` should take `enemy.pos` parameter but `enemy.pos` must be rect style object.

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is game code:

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.run = True
        self.screen_width = 1060
        self.screen_height = 798
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bin/sprites/background/background1.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.screen_width, self.screen_height))

        # all_sprites is used to update and draw all sprites together.
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # for collision detection with enemies.
        self.bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # for collision detection with walls.
        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.tank = Tank()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.tank)

        self.enemy = Enemy()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.enemy)
        self.enemy_group.add(self.enemy)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
            self.all_sprites.add(bullet)

        # -------------- Walls --------------

        wallx = [0, 0, 1044, 0, 0, 260, 146, 130, 146, 146, 130, 146, 390, 522, 390, 260, 390, 406, 522, 522, 522, 652,
                 652, 782, 914, 782, 782, 914, 914, 914, 652, 652, 782, ]
        wally = [0, 0, 0, 782, 260, 0, 130, 130, 522, 390, 652, 652, 0, 0, 130, 260, 260, 390, 260, 260, 522, 130, 130,
                 0, 0, 260, 390, 390, 522, 652, 522, 652, 522, ]
        wallWidth = [16, 1060, 16, 1060, 130, 16, 130, 16, 130, 130, 16, 130, 16, 16, 148, 146, 16, 132, 16, 130, 16,
                     278, 16, 16, 16, 278, 148, 16, 148, 148, 146, 146, 16, ]
        wallHeight = [798, 16, 798, 16, 16, 130, 16, 408, 16, 16, 146, 16, 146, 146, 16, 16, 408, 16, 146, 16, 260, 16,
                      296, 146, 146, 16, 16, 148, 16, 16, 16, 16, 276]

        for i in range(len(wallx)):
            self.wall = Wall(wallx[i], wally[i], wallWidth[i], wallHeight[i])
            self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
            self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)


    def handle_events(self):

        self.enemy.handle_events()

        # responsible for colliding with walls
        tank_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.tank.pos)
        self.tank.handle_events()
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.tank, self.wall_list, False):
            self.tank.pos = tank_pos
            self.tank.rect.center = round(tank_pos[0]), round(tank_pos[1])



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.run = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.run = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = Bullet(self.tank)
                    self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
                    self.all_sprites.add(bullet)

    def update(self):
        # Calls `update` methods of all contained sprites.
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def player_score(self):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("bin/font/Montserrat.ttf", 35)
        tank_score = font.render("PLAYER: " + str(self.tank.score), 1, dark_gray)
        self.screen.blit(tank_score, (200, 750))


    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)  # Draw the contained sprites.
        self.player_score()
        pygame.display.update()


class Tank(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bin/sprites/player/player_tank1.png")
        self.org_image = self.image.copy()

        # A nicer way to set the start pos with `get_rect`.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(70, 600))

        self.vel = 3

        self.angle = 270  # starts looking right
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)

        self.hp = 1
        self.score = 0


    def handle_events(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.angle += 3
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.angle -= 3
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and self.rect.left - 5 > 0 and self.rect.top - 5 > 0 and self.rect.right + 5 < 1060 and self.rect.bottom + 5 < 798:
            self.move(-3)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.rect.left - 5 > 0 and self.rect.top - 5 > 0 and self.rect.right + 5 < 1060 and self.rect.bottom + 5 < 798:
            self.move(3)

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.org_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


    def move(self, vel):
        direction = pygame.Vector2(0, vel).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.pos += direction
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bin/sprites/enemy/enemy_tank.png")
        self.org_image = self.image.copy()

        self.spawnx = [600, 850, 860]  # spawning x coord
        self.spawny = [70, 200, 700]  # spawning y coord
        self.i = random.randint(0, len(self.spawnx) - 1)

        # A nicer way to set the start pos with `get_rect`.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.spawnx[self.i], self.spawny[self.i]))


        self.vel = 3
        self.hp = 1
        self.score = 0

        if self.i == 0:
            self.angle = 180
        elif self.i == 1:
            self.angle = 90
        elif self.i == 2:
            self.angle = 0

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        #self.rect = self.pos

    def handle_events(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.angle += 3
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.angle -= 3
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.move(-3)
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.move(3)

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.org_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def move(self, vel):
        direction = pygame.Vector2(0, vel).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.pos += direction
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])


class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        # Make a wall, of the size specified in the parameters
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(dark_gray) # change wall color

        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, tank):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bin/sprites/bullet/bullet.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (16, 16))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = tank.rect.centerx + 3  # How much pixels from tank turret on x axis
        self.rect.centery = tank.rect.centery - 25  # How much pixels from tank turret on y axis
        self.angle = tank.angle
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(0, -10).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.lives = 4  # how many times bounces

    def update(self):

        self.pos += self.direction
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])

        for wall in game.wall_list:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):  # if collided
                if self.rect.centerx < wall.rect.left:
                    self.direction.x *= -1
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                    self.lives -= 1
                    if self.lives == 0:
                        return self.kill()
                    bounce.play()
                    #break  # break so don't check every other wall
                if self.rect.centerx > wall.rect.right:
                    self.direction.x *= -1
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                    self.lives -= 1
                    if self.lives == 0:
                        return self.kill()
                    bounce.play()
                    #break
                if self.rect.centery < wall.rect.top:
                    self.direction.y *= -1
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                    self.lives -= 1
                    if self.lives == 0:
                        return self.kill()
                    bounce.play()
                    #break
                if self.rect.centery > wall.rect.bottom:
                    self.direction.y *= -1
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
                    self.lives -= 1
                    if self.lives == 0:
                        return self.kill()
                    bounce.play()
                    #break

        enemy = Enemy()
        if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
            self.lives -= 2
            if self.lives <= 0:
                return self.kill()
            bounce.play()
```

```
def main():
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tank Trouble')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    game = Game()


    while game.run:
        game.handle_events()
        game.update()
        game.draw()
        clock.tick(fps)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_menu()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Add the code which would allow someone to execute _"enemy spawns and I shoot at it, the collision counts. But as soon as I move the enemy and shoot at it again"_, to re-create the bug/issue. Possibly whatever you've put in `if __name__ == '__main__'` or another script which imports your classes and performs those actions

Comment: I have edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance of Enemy in the update function of Bullet before checking if the bullet has collided with that instance of Enemy. This means that you are always spawning an enemy at it's default location and only checking collision with that one enemy.

What you should do instead is check if the bullet collides with any already existing enemies. There are many ways to do this. You could pass the list of enemies into the Bullet's constructor, you could use a global variable, you can use a getter function.

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ...
    def update(self):
        ...
        enemy_list = #Get all enemies here somehow
        for enemy in enemy_list:
            if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                self.lives -= 2
                if self.lives <= 0:
                    return self.kill()
                bounce.play()
```

Comment: i tried to put `game.enemy_group` in `enemy_list` but still, it doesn't detect collision

Comment: @kovels How did you initialize `game`?

Comment: I have updated the code above. At the bottom of code is how I initialize `game`

Comment: @kovels Does it collide with any walls too? From the way you initialized it, it should not be a global variable.

Comment: The player collides with walls, the enemy doesn't. But I've found where is the problem, just don't know how to solve it. In the line `if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):` it takes `enemy.rect` from `def __init__(self):` but should take from `def handle_events(self):` of the class `Enemy`

Comment: @kovels I meant bullets. Do the bullets collide with walls? Also, that's not how classes work. The object attributes are not bounded within functions. They are bounded within the object. `enemy.rect` in `__init__` is the same as in `handle_events`

Comment: Bullets collide with walls. I mean when I `print(self.rect)` in `__init__` it prints only spawning values but  when I `print(self.rect)` in `handle_events` it prints values constantly(also when I drive). So I am assuming that `if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect)` takes only first self.rect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211356/discussion-between-wxker-and-kovels).